# Asking for "huawei_scan" plugin for flutter

Tags: flutter

In flutter , Is the **huawei_scan** plugin only for **Huawei** phone ? can not use for other Phone ?

Answer (score 0):

Supports also Android 4.4 / iOS 9 or later.

See [Supported Devices](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/service-introduction-0000001050041994#section24083313595).